# Type of a function that changes the type of its input in-place

Tags: typescript

In Typescript, how would I annotate the type of a function that changes the type of its input? For example:

```js
interface Raw {
    created: string;
}
interface Processed {
    created: Date;
}

// Converts the input Raw into a Processed.
export function process(raw: Raw): void {
    (raw as unknown as Processed).created = new Date(raw.created);
}

//...

function printSeconds(r: Raw): void {
    process(r);
    console.log(r.created.getSeconds()); // compile error
}
```

How do I type a function that changes its input from one definite type to another? I could type the input as `Raw | Processed`, but then I have to use `as` in a *lot* of places.

The somewhat obvious solution is to just take a `Raw` and *return* the equivalent `Processed` from `process`, but the idea here is to use that kind of function on objects much larger than a `Raw` or `Processed`, and not just them, but on large arrays like `things.map(process)`. So making copies of everything could use non-negligible amounts of extra memory.

Comment: You can't do this; it would be possible to *narrow* from `string | Date` to just `Date`, but TypeScript does not support arbitrary type mutations.  It might be premature optimization to care about memory issues, but if it is a problem you don't have to make copies of the actual objects if you return the new type, as long as you stop using the old reference and start using the new one.  In any case I'm hoping you can produce a [mre] with no unrelated errors, since [currently your code](https://tsplay.dev/w11RGw) complains about your implementation of `process`, and...

Comment: ...all objects and non-nullish primitives [have `toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toLocaleString) so you probably should pick some other method to demonstrate

Comment: Does [this code](https://tsplay.dev/WJ8YkN) meet your needs?  You are not mutating the type of `r` but you are not creating new objects either.  Or does [this code](https://tsplay.dev/w2KV8N) meet your needs where you're using `Raw | Processed` instead of `Raw`?  If either of those does I can write up an answer; if not, please [edit] your example code to demonstrate a failing use case.

Comment: _"It might be premature optimization to care about memory issues"_ it isn't, I promise.

_"... stop using the old reference and start using the new one"_ sounds like it would still be making copies, but you just hope that it isn't missed by the time the gc runs. If I do `raws.map(process)` where `process` is a `(r: raw) => processed` then how many `raws` exist halfway through the `map`'s execution if it has length `n`? That seems implementation-defined at best. It may be all I can hope for, but it still leaves me unimpressed with Typescript.

Comment: Oh, I see, I think I misunderstood based on your example what you meant by _"... stop using the old reference and start using the new one"_. I had hoped for a better solution than the one you're proposing, but it seems that one doesn't exist from what you're telling me.

Comment: Do you consider `const foo = bar` to be "copying" `bar`?  EDIT: just saw your message, nvm

Comment: What about the `Raw | Processed` solution [here](//tsplay.dev/w2KV8N)? Type systems generally do not track type mutations but narrowing from `Raw | Processed` to `Processed` is valid. Or, what about just adding a new property instead of mutating the old one?  Like [this](//tsplay.dev/mAVOXW)?  I'm happy to write any of these up, but the "better" solution you're looking for might be to turn off type checking if strong typing is a hindrance and not a help.

Comment: I think for my use-case a better solution is going to be to just always pretend `created` is a Date, and make sure that their point of entry into the program (they're API data, so it's fairly easy to ensure) converts that property with some type-casting. There's no good way to do it for that one method, but outside of there nobody needs to know about the ugliness that lurks beneath the surface.

Comment: Right, sounds like you're just turning off type checking during the transition from `Raw` to `Processed`.  So, uh, does that mean none of those potential solutions I posted are likely to be acceptable to you and I should just mosey on out of here in search of greener pastures?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much. I guess this is more of a feature request for TS now.

Comment: I can't find an existing feature request like this (although there might be one); you can file one if you want, but I imagine it would be swiftly declined.